# How to get a list of running processes including the ports of the services?

Tags: powershell

I already have code that compares the running services with a list of services in a .csv file now i need to also see the ports of the services and check if i can ping them.

```
#Laufende Dienste
$Service = Get-Service | where{$_.Status -eq "Running"} 
Write-Host "Laufende Services:" -ForegroundColor Red 
foreach($x in $Service){
    Write-Host $x.ServiceName
    

}    


# Standard Dienste importen
$csvfile = Import-CSV -Path "K:\Example\Example.csv"
Foreach ($x in $csvfile) {
    Write-Host $x.Name
}

#Vergleichen der Liste und laufenden Dienste
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject (get-service).servicename -DifferenceObject (import-csv K:\Newton\Servicesvergleich.csv ).name  -IncludeEqual

Write-Host "Nicht in der Liste=(<=)|In der Liste=(=)" -ForegroundColor Green
```

Comment: You don't ping (as in ICMP) ports, you ping IP addresses (or hosts). Ports don't come into play at this layer. You'll have to clarify what you mean by pinging. Other than that: getting (TCP?) ports of a process requires some steps: (a) find the process that contains the service, (b) use it's process ID to find which ports it is listening on (you can google for this, one example is [here](https://adamtheautomator.com/netstat-port/).

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the process Id of the service in order to find associated ports. `Get-Service` cmdlet does not have such property.
No worries, `Win32_Service` Cim Class has this information:

```
Get-CimInstance Win32_Service -Filter "State='Running'" | ForEach {
    $service = $_
    # TCP first
    Get-NetTCPConnection -OwningProcess $_.ProcessId -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | 
       Select @{l="ServiceName";e={$service.Name}}, LocalAddress, LocalPort, `
          OwningProcess, @{l="Protocol";e={"TCP"}} -Unique
    # Then UDP (you still can start by UDP and finish by TCP, if you prefer)
    Get-NetUDPEndpoint -OwningProcess $_.ProcessId -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | 
       Select @{l="ServiceName";e={$service.Name}}, LocalAddress, LocalPort, `
          OwningProcess, @{l="Protocol";e={"UDP"}} -Unique 
    }
```

This code is quite slow as is, but does the work, so you will have 4 properties : ServiceName, LocalAddress, LocalPort, and Protocol for services that have open ports or established connections. Services without any connection nor listening will not be listed.

ATTENTION, this will extract listeninng ports and connections from services ONLY. This will not extract all listening ports nor all connections. If you want this, simply use `Get-NetTCPConnection` and `Get-NetUDPEndpoint`.

Since the `Get-NetConnection` cmdlet can test TCP Ports only, I suggest another approach. You can find a [`Test-Port` Function here](https://adamtheautomator.com/powershell-test-port/)

Be aware that Local Addresses `0.0.0.0` and `::` are listening, if you want to test them, replace them by `127.0.0.1` or `::1`

Comment: Thanks man i only need to know the ports of the services tho but thanks for the tip with Get-NetTCPConnection and Get-NetUDPEndpoint.

Comment: Good to know win32_service has the ports.  I've used sysinternals tcpview.

Comment: @js2010 `Win32_Service` does not expose the ports, only the `ProcessId` property that you can use to get the associated ports with `Get-NetTCPConnection` and `Get-NetUDPEndpont`